# Consequences of using kill -9 for node processes?

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb

When reading [mongodb's documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-kill) one of the thing that stood out was:

> ***WARNING***:
>
> Never use kill -9 (i.e. SIGKILL) to terminate a mongod instance.

I've been running into issues while using `foreman start` to start my node server. Foreman will start up multiple node processes with the same PID.

However the problem is that when I stop my node process, node won't actually stop running and continues to use the port it was listening on.

To work around this I've been using `sudo kill -9 <PID>` for the node process I want to terminate. Are there any negative consequences to doing this?

Also, why does Mongo warn against using kill -9 to terminate a mongod instance?

Comment: *"Also, why does Mongo warn against using kill -9 to terminate a mongod instance?"* my wild guess would be to avoid loss of data. you wouldn't want to kill the process in the middle of a transaction.

Comment: Perhaps you are not patient enough using other signal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't give the process a chance to cleanly:

1) shut down socket connections

2) clean up temp files

3) inform its children that it is going away

4) reset its terminal characteristics

These are the bad consequences of what can happen when you use `kill -9`. You should only use `kill -9` as a last resort if all else has failed.

And to the second question, because `kill -9` will kill the process even if it is in the middle of doing something while `kill` will shutdown the process after a clean exit.

Comment: If I had to use ```kill -9``` is there a way for me to manually do those 4 steps? (shut down socket connections, clean up temp files, etc)

Comment: No, because those actions are dependent on the process's code. If you kill it, it can no longer be done. You can probably do some manual work by browsing `/tmp`, but the sockets are long gone and the connected processes have received a nasty error by that time.

Answer (score 2):

Using `SIGKILL` (`-9`) instead of the more common `SIGTERM` (no parameters) or `SIGHUP` (`-1`) means the process is killed at the OS level. Mongo keeps a lot of data in memory as cache, both for reading and writing. Using `SIGKILL` could therefore mean data was half-written to disk, or will never get written at all. In either case you could get a corrupted database, or end up missing data that was communicated to users or other processes as being successfully stored.  'Classical' database systems work around this problem by using transaction logs (a kernel panic or power failure is essentially the same effect), but Mongo is considered 'nosql' for good reasons, including prominently its lack of transactional integrity.

This only goes for the server process of course, you can kill your node processes any way you want from mongo's perspective. However, in general you should avoid using `kill -9` to kill **any** process, for the same reasons outlined above. Processes that can't clean up tend to leave a mess behind. The usual order is:

```
kill <pid>
```

...Sends `SIGTERM`, requesting a graceful shutdown, so wait 30 seconds for the process to close, if it is still alive:

```
kill -1 <pid>
```

...Sends `SIGHUP`, requesting immediate shutdown, wait another 30 seconds at least for the process to close, and finally:

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

...If, **and only if**, the process cannot be allowed to continue running because it is causing issues in server stability or locking resources. In all other cases, just wait.

For the differences between 'graceful' and 'immediate' shutdown mentioned above, consider having a `notepad.exe` in which you typed 2 lines. Graceful pops up a dialog asking if you want to save, immediate just shuts down cleanly without user interaction, and 'kill' stops the process right away and releases all memory and other resources back to the system. Historically the signals come from old dial-in mainframes, where `SIGHUP` is short for 'Hangup', indicating the user has left and cannot return.